# Can't find app icon in react-native ios build

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I installed it from react-native official site as below.
(node.js and openJDK were installed differently)

**Version information**

- Mac OSX : Mojave 10.14.6
- XCode : Version 11.0 (11A420a)
- node(nvm) : 10.15
- react: 16.9.0
- react-native : 0.61.1
- react-native-cli : 2.0.1
- watchman : 4.9.0
- openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

**XCode Preferences**
Locations > Command Line Tools : Xcode 11.0 (11A420a)
Components > Simulator : iOS 12.2, iOS 12.1, iOS 11.1, iOS 11.0

Changed the configuration from podfile to `platform: ios, '9.0'` to `platform: ios, '11.0 '`.

**code execute**

```sh
react-native init rntest
react-native run-ios
```

(I don't see an app icon to launch.)

**watchman error message**

```
Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2019-10-03T03:19:20,686: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/myname-state/sock! (No such file or directory)
```

What should I do to run react-native's initial app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have watchman installed properly? 
What happens when you run `watchman --foreground --logfile=/dev/stdout`

Please try entering the following command:

```
chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/run/watchman/yourname-state
```

Don't forget to change the "yourname" to your user name or whatever you have it there!